# Setting android datepicker min date to specific date

Tags: android, datepicker, android-datepicker

I want the user to be able to pick start date and end date. The minimum of end date must be equal to start date. For example the user selects August 1 2014 as a start date. When he clicks on the return date field these values are passed to date_picker_activity as intent extras. In the date_picker_activity I check for these extras and currently it just sets the selected date as the displayed date:

```
if(getIntent().getExtras()!=null)
{
    int year = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("SELECTED_YEAR");
    int month = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("SELECTED_MONTH");
    int day = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("SELECTED_DAY");
    date_picker.updateDate(year, month, day);
}
```

but the user is still able to pick dates prior to selected start date.

I tried to do something like that inside that if statement:

```
Time time = new Time();
time.set(day, month, year);
date_picker.setMinDate(time.toMillis(true)-1000);
```

but that didn't work.

How can I set the min date with the passed values?

Comment: inside onDateSet(), check if year, month and day values are acceptable.

Comment: onDateSet() is a method of DatePickerDialog, right? I'm not using it, I'm using an activity that has DatePicker element in the layout XML.

Comment: OK, I'll edit my answer, then.

Comment: Why do you say that did not work? Your code seems to be right.

Comment: Yes, the code works with setting the value of the DatePicker to start date, but it doesn't prevent the user from setting the date prior to it. So if the start date, for example, is Augist 1 2014, currently the user can set the end date to July 29 2014, and I want to prevent it.

Comment: Are you sure the values coming from the Intent are not empty?

Comment: Absolutely sure! In fact it's being checked 2 times - the first time I'm checking if the start_date is set, and only if it is - the date_picker_activity can be opened, and the second time in the activity itself (checking that intent extras aren't empty).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58107/discussion-between-joao2fast4u-and-igal).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After discussing on chat, we managed to understand that this code:

```
date_picker.setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
```

was being called anyway inside the if statement, setting the minimum date to the current Date.

Once Igal moved that code to an else statement, all is working ok.

Comment: And once again, thank you very much for giving me the push to right direction! Appreciate your help! :)